# Wildfly runs properly but wars Faile

Tags: java, xml, wildfly

I have a wildfly project. My supervisor sent me the latest version of it and told me what paths I have to change to run it. At the end of the day, I got this in the console:
[image]

He told me everything looked okay, but this is what I got on the deployments section
[image]

I do not manage this technology, it´s my first time using it.

I have deleted all the war.deployed files, but when they deploy again I got the same error

Comment: You will have to check the WildFly logs to see what exactly caused deployment to fail.

Comment: There are several errors, but My team also has many of them. I can show you the log, maybe you can see the error